# UISplitViewController getting the wrong details ViewController in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an extension of UISplitViewController for getting the Details and Master ViewControllers.
For passing data from Master to details.

```
extension UISplitViewController {

/// returns the details UIViewController
var details: UIViewController {
    get {

        if let detailsNavigation = viewControllers.last as? UINavigationController {
            return detailsNavigation.viewControllers.first!
        } else {
            return viewControllers.last!
        }
    }
}

/// returns the master UIViewController
var master: UIViewController {
    get {

        if let masterNavigation = viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController {
            return masterNavigation.viewControllers.first!
        } else {
            return viewControllers.first!
        }
    }
}
}
```

In landscape everything works great.

In portrait the data doesn't get passed and the details doesn't appear on screen.

Also, When i log the splitViewController's ViewControllers.

In portrait i get the Master for both master and details (from my extension)

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE -

When i print out the splitViewController's
in portrait mode i get

```
(lldb) po splitViewController!.viewControllers
▿ 1 elements
  - [0] : <UINavigationController: 0x7fa9ce014400>
```

and in landscape mode i get:

```
(lldb) po splitViewController!.viewControllers
▿ 2 elements
  - [0] : <UINavigationController: 0x7fa9ce014400>
  - [1] : <UINavigationController: 0x7fa9ce02fc00>
```

Where does the Details disappear to?

---

UPDATE 2 -

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISplitViewController/viewControllers) it says that when only one ViewController is on screen the viewControllers property only has one ViewController.

So how can i get the DetailsViewController?
Do i need to instantiate it every time?

Comment: i get the masters viewController

Comment: I run 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/94443/uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started
and i get the same result.

They save a weak reference to the detailViewController to show it.

is there a different way to get the detailsViewController from the master?